# How to use azure disk in AKS environment

Tags: azure-aks

I am trying to setup the AKS in which I have used azure disk to mount the source code of the application. When I am using kubectl describe pods command then also it is showing as mounted but I dont know how may I copy the code into that?
I got some recommendations that use kubectl cp command but my pod name is changing each time whenever I am deploying so please let me know what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

you'd need to copy files to the disk directly (not to the pod). you can use your pod or worker node to do that. You can use `kubectl cp` to copy files to the pod and then move it to the mounted disk like you normally would. or you can ssh to the worker node and copy files over ssh to the node and put files to the mounted disk.